# Dock Gboard keyboard to the bottom

Tags: gboard

I think Android pushed an update on to my Pixel 3 phone running Android 10, and now the Gboard keyboard is small and floats around.

How do I dock the Gboard keyboard at the bottom of the screen?

Answer (score 4):

On the keyboard, click the three dots "..." and click on "Floating" to unfloat/dock

Comment: Thanks for this! I know it's a bit older but it was exactly what I needed. Wanted to give it the upvote it deserves. :)